# How to convert a chart with kernel density estimation line from d3.js version 3 to d3.js version 4

Tags: d3.js

I have a chart with kernel density estimation line (created with science.js). Currently, d3 version 3 is used here, I need this to be converted to version 4 of d3.js.

Please Help.

JSBin/Code Link: http://jsbin.com/nuzucibiju/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>LOESS</title>
    <script src="http://bl.ocks.org/curran/raw/b595fde4d771c5784421/science.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <style>

      body {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
      }

      path {
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
        fill: none;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vis">
    </div>
    <script>
      
     // Based on http://bl.ocks.org/900762 by John Firebaugh
     
        var data = [
  79, 54, 74, 62, 85, 55, 88, 85, 51, 85, 54, 84, 78, 47, 83, 52, 62, 84, 52, 79, 51, 47, 78, 69, 74, 83, 55, 76, 78, 79, 73, 77, 66, 80, 74, 52, 48, 80, 59, 90, 80, 58, 84, 58, 73, 83, 64, 53,
  82, 59, 75, 90, 54, 80, 54, 83, 71, 64, 77, 81, 59, 84, 48, 82, 60, 92, 78, 78, 65, 73, 82, 56, 79, 71, 62, 76, 60, 78, 76, 83, 75, 82, 70, 65, 73, 88, 76, 80, 48, 86, 60, 90, 50, 78, 63, 72,
  84, 75, 51, 82, 62, 88, 49, 83, 81, 47, 84, 52, 86, 81, 75, 59, 89, 79, 59, 81, 50, 85, 59, 87, 53, 69, 77, 56, 88, 81, 45, 82, 55, 90, 45, 83, 56, 89, 46, 82, 51, 86, 53, 79, 81, 60, 82, 77,
  76, 59, 80, 49, 96, 53, 77, 77, 65, 81, 71, 70, 81, 93, 53, 89, 45, 86, 58, 78, 66, 76, 63, 88, 52, 93, 49, 57, 77, 68, 81, 81, 73, 50, 85, 74, 55, 77, 83, 83, 51, 78, 84, 46, 83, 55, 81, 57,
  76, 84, 77, 81, 87, 77, 51, 78, 60, 82, 91, 53, 78, 46, 77, 84, 49, 83, 71, 80, 49, 75, 64, 76, 53, 94, 55, 76, 50, 82, 54, 75, 78, 79, 78, 78, 70, 79, 70, 54, 86, 50, 90, 54, 54, 77, 79, 64,
  75, 47, 86, 63, 85, 82, 57, 82, 67, 74, 54, 83, 73, 73, 88, 80, 71, 83, 56, 79, 78, 84, 58, 83, 43, 60, 75, 81, 46, 90, 46, 74
]; 
    
        var w = 952,
            h = 476,
            x = d3.scale.linear().domain([30, 110]).range([0, w]),
            bins = d3.layout.histogram().frequency(false).bins(x.ticks(60))(data),
            max = d3.max(bins, function(d) { return d.y; }),
            y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, .1]).range([0, h]),
            kde = science.stats.kde().sample(data); 

        var vis = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

        var bars = vis.selectAll("g.bar")
            .data(bins)
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              
              return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + (h - y(d.y)) + ")";
            });

        bars.append("rect")
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")
            .attr("width", function(d) { 
                     
          return x(d.dx + 30) - 1; })
        
            .attr("height", function(d) { 
          console.log('height',d);
          return y(d.y); });

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
            .y(function(d) { return h - y(d[1]); });
 
        vis.selectAll("path")
            .data(d3.values(science.stats.bandwidth))
          .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", function(h) {
              return line(kde.bandwidth(h)(d3.range(30, 110, .1)));
            });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to convert d3.js v3 to v4 but getting a lot of errors.

It would be great if the chart is converted to the desired version 4.

[SourceCode](http://jsbin.com/nuzucibiju/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read [this article](https://swizec.com/blog/histogram-d3v3-d3v4/swizec/7145). It is a great explanation how histogram was changed in d3v4 compared to d3v3.

You should rewrite your code this way:

```
var w = 952,
  h = 476,
  x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([30, 110]).range([0, w]),
  bins = d3.histogram().domain(x.domain()).thresholds(x.ticks(30))(data),
  max = d3.max(bins, function(d) { return d.y; }),
  y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, .1]).range([0, h]),
  yForHistogram = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) { return d.length; })])
  .range([h, 0]),
  kde = science.stats.kde().sample(data);

var vis = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var bars = vis.selectAll("g.bar")
  .data(bins)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + yForHistogram(d.length) + ")"; });

bars.append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("width", x(bins[0].x1) - x(bins[0].x0) - 1)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return h - yForHistogram(d.length);
  });
...
```

Check my [fork of JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cowehahaba/edit?html,js,output) that you mentioned. It works with d3v4.